# Prove the number of decompositions is finite

Tags: sequences-and-series, rational-numbers

> Let $a,n$ two positive integers. Prove:
>
> 1. There is a sequence $a_1, a_2, ... a_n$ of positive integers such that:
>      $$1+ \frac 1 a = \prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1 + \frac 1 {a_k}\right)$$
> 2. The number of the above sequences is finite.

(1) is easy to prove by taking $a_i = an + (i-1), 1 \le i \le n$, but I can't prove (2). I tried to use induction by $n$ but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2. Each $a_k$ has to be $>a$, otherwise $\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{a_k}\right)$ would be greater than $1+\frac{1}{a}$. On the other hand, by the AM-GM inequality
   $$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{a_k}\right)\leq \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{a_k}\right)^n $$
   hence the average value of $\frac{1}{a_k}$ has to be $\geq -1+\left(1+\frac{1}{a}\right)^{1/n}\approx\frac{1}{na}$.
    In particular there are at most a finite number of sequences fulfilling 1.

Comment: The remark $a_k \gt a$ is useless, right? It is enough that $a_k$ is positive.

Comment: @EugenCovaci: yes, it is pretty useless, it is there just to show that we have a double bound, both from above and from below (at least on average).

Comment: Very ingenious, thank you.